# How to check if $routeParams data exists

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to see if there is a way to redirect or perform any action based upon data existing at firebase location using routeParams in angularfire.  If I have a user profile $routeParam setup, and the user object exists for user1,(users/user1), I would like to display that profile.  However, if the user object doesn't exist for user20, instead of showing the template page with blank data, I would like to redirect to another page.  I'm not sure where to make this call.
Here is my Profile Controller setup

```
app.controller('ProfileCtrl',
function ($scope, $routeParams, User) {
    $scope.user = User.findUsername($routeParams.username);
```

and my User Service for checking if the user exists

```
 findUsername: function (username) {
        if (username) {
            return users.$child(username);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
app.controller('ProfileCtrl',
    function ($scope, $routeParams, User,$location) {
      if(!$routeParams.username){
         $location.path('/somewhereElse');
      }

    $scope.user = User.findUsername($routeParams.username);
```

If you mean if you want to check if the username is a valid one, the only way to do so is through some check, ideally server side with `$http`. I would suggest making a service to check the server for valid usernames.

Comment: Great, I will look at creating a service to check the username.  Do you know of any resources?

Comment: @RonThomson You need to make an angular Service that makes a `GET` request to your back end and checks against a database whether the entered UserName is valid or not, i.e. it exists in the Users table of your database.

Comment: @MohammadSepahvand wont it throw 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined' if used on route where this particular property does not exist

Answer (score 0):

if the parameter is optional and not present then $routeParams will be undefined and the above will fail. To avoid this just simply check for $routeParams as well

```
if($routeParams && routeParams.username) {
    $scope.user = User.findUsername($routeParams.username);
}
```